# Disable scroll to focused button

Tags: blackberry

Hi a have two buttons at the bottom of the screen and each time I open this screen, view is scrolled to the bottom to show those focused buttons, is there any method to disable this behaviour and firstly display top of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a focusable field to the top of your screen. Its up to you how you want to achieve this, but generally you can put a `NullField` as the first view of your screen.

The `NullField` should receive the initial focus for you, but note a user can still scroll back to it as with any other view. So it might look like your focus is "lost" depending on how your design looks.

```
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public MyScreen()
    {
        super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
        add(new NullField()); // Nullfield to be initially focused

        // Screen content with focusable button at the bottom
        add(new LabelField("Label"));
        ButtonField button = new ButtonField("Button");
        button.setMargin(1000, 0, 0, 0);
        add(button);
    }
}
```